# Acrobat DC PRO save settings are greyed out NO FILE SAVE settings in settings

Tags: adobe-acrobat

So I have a document that I am trying to print out.  I cropped it in half so I can print it out on 2 sheets.  Acrobat says that it "Optimized it for WEB" when I saved it.  Well ok gee I'm not going to view this on the web I am printing this out and do not want my document I paid for to be compromised when I crop it.

[image: IMG:]

So why are the settings greyed out when I save?  Why is there no options shown in the preferences ?  I see I can save as other and then I can tell it not to save it but why are there no options for the regular save ?  I am guessing I have to save as other and tell it not to reduce the quality of my document. ?

Comment: Is there a specific change you are looking to apply prior to saving? Chances are that you'll find it elsewhere in the menus and tools and can apply it prior to saving. Those settings are only relevant when saving to a different format. You'll notice that if you change the "Save as type" drop-down, that button will no longer be greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

`Save as… saves optimized for fast web view` can be a culprit here, but does not need to. However, it may be better to turn this option off, and see if the effect remains.

OTOH, the `Settings` button being greyed out when saving as a PDF is normal behavior, because there are no specific options to be selected when writing a PDF from a PDF. Or would you expect something to be set here?